# Override System Environment Variables syntax in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, environment-variables

I know that the syntax for expanding system Environment Variables on Windows is `%VAR%`.

I just wondered -out of curiosity- if there were a way to override this in any manner. So entering e.g. `@var` (or ... don't know... `§var`, whatever) in the Explorer address bar would navigate to the Directory saved for 'var'.

The motivation for the question is, I actively use system variables in my daily doing (esp. my own user-vars) and entering the 2x '%' is kind of uncomfortable...

Comment: That's like saying, "I don't like to write *n++* or *++n* to increment in C++." Write your own OS.

Comment: Btw, that's exactly what snippets do in VS, no need to write an own IDE... 

Answer (score 0):

This will be written into the OS at a deep level that would be very difficult extricate.

Windows code has been, for a long time, predicated on this foundational principle.

Is it theoretically possible that this could be changed? Maybe, but it would be so difficult that, as the commenter noted, you would need to rewrite the OS.

They weren't being mean or upset: they were speaking the realistic truth.

Comment: I was rather thinking of a kind a explorer-extension, just like for the contextmenu, than writing a new OS. . Could have been, someone tried something similar in the past. I admit, could have been more specific... Thank you for taking time.

Comment: We don't entertain requests for software recommendations on this site for various reasons, detailed in the Help section. You could also rethink your needs and the question. The OS cannot be told that some other prefix is a system variable, but depending on the circumstances you confine this use case to (a particular scripting tool, or narrow and specific utility) you may be able to write functions that rewrite your scripts, or a persistent automation tool like AutoHotKey that can interpret your code into something the OS understands. BUT you're only saving one keystroke, and really, why?

Comment: I know, this is not a wish-list of MS :-) This wasn't my intent. I just wondered if anyone maybe did try some Adressbar-Extensions in the past (or whether this is even possible). Regarding your question 'why', it's not about the count of keystrokes, rather the 'flow' in typing. In this particular case you enter either the 2 '%', then move back the caret, or enter first Key-combo, enter the value and then the Key-Combo again. Don't take me wrong, I don't wanna change the world here, just wanted to probe, if I could tweak it a little bit for my own comfort. :-)